# Setting a batch script or EXE as default browser in Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, default

At my company we have to test our apps in IE, but I prefer using Chrome as my default browser. I made the following simple batch script in an attempt to launch the link in IE if it's related to my company, or to launch it in Chrome otherwise. The script looks like below and seems to work well from the command line.

```
set url=%1
echo %url%|findstr /i companyname >nul:
if %errorlevel%==1  goto :co_not_found
:co_found
    "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %url%
    goto :gensuite_end
:co_not_found
    "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %url%
:co_end
```

Now I've been trying for days to get this little doodad set as the default browser for my computer. Here's a list of some of the registry keys I've edited. For some reason, Windows is still using IE as the default browser.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartmenuInternet  (Default) = DEFAULTBROWSER
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\http  (Default) = C:\browserFix.exe
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\http\shell\open\command  (Default) = C:\browserFix.exe
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\https  (Default) = C:\browserFix.exe
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\https\shell\open\command  (Default) = C:\browserFix.exe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command  (Default) = C:\browserFix.exe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\https\shell\open\command  (Default) = C:\browserFix.exe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet (Default) = DEFAULTBROWSER
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\DEFAULTBROWSER  (Default) = Default Browser, LocalizedString = C:\browserFix.exe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\DEFAULTBROWSER\shell\open\command  (Default) = C:\browserFix.exe
```

If I go to the control panel > programs > default programs > associate a file type or protocol and double click on HTTP or HTTPS, I'm only given the options for Google Chrome and IE. There is no browse option. In the end I'd like to be able to do this programmatically anyway. But to see if I could get it to show up I based these entries off of the ones for Google Chrome.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\DEFAULTBROWSER\Capabilities\StartMenu  StartMenuInternet = Default Browser Fixer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\DEFAULTBROWSER\Capabilities\URLAssociations  http and https = C:\browserFix.exe
```

It looks like Windows still isn't even looking at the program as a browser, much less the default one. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Keep in mind that I'd like to be able to do this with an installer batch script in the future.

Thanks in advance!
Jake

Comment: See this great answer
http://superuser.com/questions/368814/how-do-i-change-my-default-browser-to-an-unlisted-program-in-windows-7 Also remember the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT entries for .html
.htm http
https
ftp

Answer (score 0):

A program must have registry entries indicating that it can handle particular types of files.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx and links therefrom for details of the registry entries required in general, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx for how to register URI protocol handlers.